# Reconciling Kafka Topic Timestamp with Kafka Connect Sink Connector Commit Time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, camel-kafka-connector

I am using the following to dump topic with its timestamps & offsets:

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 \
  --consumer.config $KAFKA_HOME/config/consumer.properties \
  --property print.timestamp=true \
  --property print.partition=true \
  --property print.offset=true \
  --topic test-topic \
  --from-beginning \
  --timeout-ms 5000
```

This gives me:

```
CreateTime:1691324282543        Partition:4     Offset:279076
```

Note: (1691324282543=6 August 2023 12:18:02.543)

My sink connector looks like this

```
connector.class=org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.googlepubsub.CamelGooglepubsubSinkConnector
camel.sink.path.destinationName=input_topic
errors.log.include.messages=true
errors.retry.timeout=300000
tasks.max=6
topics=test-topic
errors.retry.delay.max.ms=60000
camel.sink.contentLogLevel=DEBUG
camel.component.google-pubsub.serviceAccountKey=file:/tmp/gcp/gcp.json
type=sink
errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable=true
kafka.partition.count=6
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name=test-topic-Failed
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
errors.tolerance=all
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
camel.sink.path.projectId=******
errors.log.enable=true
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

Now if I look at the sink connector logs I get

```
[2023-08-06 11:48:50,275] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=test-sink-connector-4} Finished offset commit successfully in 5 ms for sequence number 16822: {test-topic-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=279076, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:272)
```

Why does the sink connector write it to the sink 30 mins before the offset is created in the topic?

Thanks